# Website Data Log History ($10k lost)

Tags: forensics, chrome, data-recovery

I have lost access to a web wallet for a cryptocoin. That website generated an unique "seed" (private key) client-side and I forgot to write down that seed to access my wallet later on. So my question is: Is website data (generated by JS) of Chrome stored somewhere on my computer? I don't think so but to get back about 10000$ I just wanted to be sure...

Browser: Chrome
OS: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Edit: Some [moneros](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/monero/) to givaway for the one with the correct answer...

Comment: I assume that the private key was then sent to the website through a POST request, which then generated the wallet on the website.  The POST request will be in the browser history cache.  But you need to provide us with more info: how long ago did you create the wallet by that method (if 10 000 USD have been loaded into the wallet it may have been some time ago), the link to the website may be helpful as well.

Comment: No, according to the developer of that site (http://mymonero.com), the private key is generated client-side only due to security reasons. You can try it out by generated your own private key (https://mymonero.com/#/create-your-account) My key was generated on 19th september 2016. After logging in into my wallet, I made a transaction to this wallet and logged out. Didn't notice that I hadn't stored my seed somewhere until the last week.